# How to pass selected value from a dynamically created dropdown to another one? Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net

I have a subroutine that is adding tblcells to a table on an aspx form. A simplified example of one tblcell:

```
    tblcell = New TableCell
    inputDrop = New DropDownList
    inputDrop.ID = "drop_" & tableType & "_optionname" & tableCount
    inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select one", ""))
    inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("ANY", "ANY"))
    inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem(row("option_name"),  
    Next
    inputDrop.CssClass = "dropWidths"
    tblcell.Controls.Add(inputDrop)
    tblrow.Cells.Add(tblcell)
```

I need the selected value of this tblcell to pass into a subroutine to find the options for the next tblcell dropdown. This subroutine gets called on page load every postback. We define an "ID" for the dropdown, but I am not sure if I can use this with .SelectedValue somehow.

I'm also unsure of the post back triggers for something like this, and where to place them on the aspx front page code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event to the DropDownList that is loaded on page load. When you handle that event you populate the second DropDownList. Also make sure that you don't re-run the code for the first dropdown on postback. The first dropdown list should have the postback property enabled. Since you are creating it on the code behind you set the property in the code behind not on the aspx.  I can write the code for you but I rather give you a basic idea on what's needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I don't re-run the code for the first drop down on postback, will it persist on the page after postback? And my biggest problem is figuring out how to specify that dropdown I want to work with. Would I use the "ID" to assign an event to it?

Comment: It will persist if your viewstate property on the page is set to true. I don't remember the exact syntax as I haven't been working with webforms in a while but to add the event you can use AddHandler inputDrop.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf <Your Handler Method>. The other drop down you want to populate you can find it by using GetControlById on its parent and then casting it to a drop down.